# the sdk manager won't open after trying everything

Tags: android, sdk

I have installed the Android SDK but I can't get the Adroid SDK manager to open.
I have looked everywhere on the internet and this is what I have already done which didn't help:

**1.** run sdk as administrator

**2.** adding a path pointing to the JDK in all of these forms :

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21\bin;%SystemRoot%\system32;

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21\bin;

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21\

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21

C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_21/bin;

none of them worked ..:-(

**3.** 
Step #1: Open up a command prompt.
Step #2: Use the cd command to move to wherever you installed your Android SDK.
Step #3: Run tools\android.

after doing it I got an error message that said that :

ERROR: No suitable Java found. In order to properly use the Android Developer
Tools, you need a suitable version of Java installed on your system.

**4.** deleting 3 times the sdk and reinstalling it.

**5.** Deleting the .android folder from the user (C:/Users/[User Name]) directory

By the way I have  Windows 7 , and I have downloaded the 64 -bits sdk. 
I am so helpless.. I ll appreciate a lot a solution...
Shiran

Comment: did you try to install it for every user on your computer or just for you?

Comment: I have only one user ..

Comment: Me, too, but I'm asking because I had a problem like this using android-studio. Installing it for everyone (although there's nobody else) didn't work, but installing only for me did.

Comment: I won't mind trying it..How do you install just for yourself ?

Comment: On Android-Studio there was an option during the installation-process, I don't know if it's in the sdk-installer. I've only tried Android-Studio and Eclipse with the ADT-plugin, never SDk standalone

Comment: It is with the ADT - plugin...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30847/discussion-between-recode-and-shiran)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Try to add an environment variable :

```
JAVA_HOME : "C:\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\".
```

It solves problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

WRT Ubuntu 14.04:

You may not have java installed globally in your machine. My fix was to do:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk
```

After was I able to run the SDK Manager.